# дискорд бот не видит команды. что делать?

Tags: python, discord.py

```
# Todo: Импорт библиотек
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import config
#from random import randint, randrange
from discord_buttons_plugin import *

# Todo:  Бот

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=config.PREFIX, intents=intents)
buttons = ButtonsClient(bot)
# Todo: Нужные переменные и настройки



bot.remove_command('help')


# Todo: Комманды

@bot.command()
async def help(ctx):
    await ctx.send('test')
    print('123')

# Todo: Запуск бота
bot.run(config.TOKEN)
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно, в настройках вашего бота отключен один из следующих параметров:

- `PRESENCE INTENT`
- `SERVER MEMBERS INTENT`
- `MESSAGE CONTENT INTENT`

Их нужно обязательно включить

Comment: вопрос как их подключить?

Comment: а, я уже разобрался, спасибо